# ERROR: Zombie Apocalypse has started

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, ripple

I have a strange error wehn trying to use the ripple emulator.
I create a project: phonegap create asdf
I enter the project: cd asdf
I compile to android: phonegap build android
after I want to use the ripple amulator: ripple emulate
Chorme opens, I see the message "device is ready" from the default project and after a few seconds it gives me this error:
"Looks like what we have here is a failure to... emulate
You're seeing this window because it looks like the zombie apocalypse has started.
For some strange reason it looks like we are unable to load. This could be a problem  with your application, with ours or that you may require more time to finish loading.  Hit "Wait" to give your application more time. Hit "FIRE!!" to pick up a shotgun and blow away all  all of Ripple's settings in an attempt to purge out the bad stuff."|
I use the latest phonegap 3.3 ant the latest ripple 0.9.20 and I have node.js installed and I have the .cordova folder.

This is the console:

```
Console was cleared ripple.js:37
Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Gray. Hot.) ripple.js:37
cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.) ripple.js:37
The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported. localhost/:25
Received Event: deviceready index.js:47
cordova :: fired deviceready event! ripple.js:37
```

Thank You!

Comment: If the zombie apocalypse has started, that gives you license to hunt down the author of these error messages with a shotgun.

Comment: Hahah... But anyway.. Do you have a clue about it?

Comment: Anybody any hep please? Is someone also having this or am I the only one from the whole planet?

Comment: All I know is, PhoneGap can be temperamental. Have you filed a bug with the Ripple project?

Comment: Yea! I mailed several times ripple support but no straight anser so far... And I hoped somebody else cand help me with this situation..

Comment: Which device is set in ripple UI? I found that when I moved from 0.9.19 to 0.9.20 with an android PhoneGap build, ripple wouldn't work as I had selected an iPhone as the device. If I changed the device to a Nexus 4, then it worked fine.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I'm using version 0.9.20 and on any device I have the problem. I saw that when I run ripple from apptana it works and at first, when the page loads I have 3 messages that I have to ignore... When I run ripple from console they appear just 2 of them and after 5 seconds or so.. itcrashes... so this problem is only when I run it from CLI.

Comment: me too on the same version 0.9.20(ripple) and phonegap(3.3).

Answer (score 5):

The error is disappeared after I removed the chrome ripple emulator extension.
You can check your browser environment.

Comment: I removed the ripple extension from chrome but it gives me a lot of errors :rror: static() root path required
    at Function.static (C:\Users\Alexandru\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:49:20)
    at Object.handle (C:\Users\Alexandru\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\server\emulate\static.js:6:27)
    at next (C:\Users\Alexandru\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:199:15)
and more others...

Comment: I am not sure that it can run on the Windows. I am on the Mac.

Comment: So there is no option to removoe that red screen of death?

Comment: You could try it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from other comments that you have had the Chrome extension for Ripple installed. This extension is no longer under active development and does not support PhoneGap 3.x. When using Ripple via the command line, the extension should be uninstalled as identified by Riceball LEE.

The error message you identified looks something like this:

```
Error: static() root path required
at Function.static (C:\Users\dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:49:20)
at Object.handle (C:\Users\dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\server\emulate\static.js:6:27)
at next (C:\Users\dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:199:15)
at handle (C:\Users\dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\server\emulate\hosted.js:156:17)
...
```

I'm guessing that it appears in the window of the emulated device and your app does not run.

The latest version of the emulator has changed the way it looks for your source files. `ripple emulate` should now be run from your app directory (i.e. the folder that contains `merge`, `platforms`, `www` etc). Ripple will expect to find the `platforms` folder and then drill down into one of the platforms to find your built `www` folder (e.g. `platforms\android\assets\www`). It is the content in this folder that will be emulated.

I have encountered this exception in Ripple 0.9.20 when building for Android. It stopped occurring when I changed my emulated device from an iOS device to an Android one. It was[this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ripple-dev/201401.mbox/%3CCAK2avF9jbNwC-JhADfJ7a=T0C8YYgTBFKy9vx9TffRtt7HkbUQ@mail.gmail.com%3E) post in the Ripple dev mailing list that led me to that solution.